# Как получить метод из AddSingleton<>()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Мне нужно создать класс который будет "жить всегда" для кэша и в Progam.cs возникла проблема вызвать класс и получить метод **GetUserBD**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCacheBD, MemoryCacheBD>(_ => new MemoryCacheBD(databaseConnectionString, new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions())));
```

У меня есть класс **MemoryCacheBD** в котором кэшируются данные из БД.

```
  public class MemoryCacheBD : IMemoryCacheBD
  {
      private readonly DBAuthorizationRoles AuthorizationRole;
      private readonly IMemoryCache cache;

      public MemoryCacheBD(string databaseConnectionString, IMemoryCache cache)
      {
          this.AuthorizationRole = new DBAuthorizationRoles(databaseConnectionString);
          this.cache = cache;
      }

      public Task<AuthorizationRoles?> GetUserBD(string Login)
      {
          //Код с кэшированием
          return Task.FromResult(User)!;
      }
}
```

Мне нужно что бы в Progam.cs во время авторизации (Events в OpenIdConnect) вызывался метод **GetUserBD** что бы получить данные, но когда пытаюсь вызвать метод

```
var user = await MemoryCacheBD.GetUserBD(Login);
```

возникает ошибка:

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства
> "MemoryCacheBD.GetUserBD(string)" требуется ссылка на объект.

Как правильно вызывать метод не делая его статичным?

**Обновление 1**
Код авторизации в Progam.cs

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("ADFS", options =>
{
    options.Authority = configuration.GetSection("ADFS")["Authority"]!;
    options.ClientId = configuration.GetSection("ADFS")["ClientId"]!;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeToken;
    options.CallbackPath = configuration.GetSection("ADFS")["CallbackPath"]!;
    options.SaveTokens = true;    
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {    
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            //Запрашиваем у сервера данные о пользователе
            var idToken = context.SecurityToken;
            var ClaimsUserInfo = idToken.Claims;
            var Login = ClaimsUserInfo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.ToString() == "winaccountname")?.Value;
            var Name = ClaimsUserInfo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.ToString() == "commonname")?.Value;
            
            AuthorizationRoles? User = await MemoryCacheBD.GetUserBD(Login);


        }
    };


});
```

Comment: _в Progam.cs во время авторизации_ - добавь код Program.cs

Comment: Добавил часть где запрашиваю данные

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть корзина яблок, вы пошли в сад и нарвали туда десяток яблок, вот вам надо помыть яблоко, ваши действия? "Яблоко.Помыть()", верно? Ок, а яблоко где? Что перед этим действием надо сделать? Правильно "Корзина.ВзятьЯблоко()", логику поняли? Вы положили в контейнер некий тип (`Services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCacheBD, MemoryCacheBD>`), вот чтоб работать с этим типом, вы должны взять контейнер, и попросить у него нужное, например `контейнер.GetService<IMemoryCacheBD>()`, либо если тип в контейнере, то через DI, то есть, через конструктор.

Comment: Если создаю конструктор с MemoryCacheBD, то данных в кэше никаких нет. Думаю проблема в том что при создании 
" new MemoryCacheBD( databaseConnectionString, new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()) ) " передаю в него новый MemoryCache. И тут возникает у меня вопрос, а как передать первоначальный MemoryCache?

Comment: Используя контейнеры, у вас вообще не должно быть `new` в коде, все инициализации берет на себя контейнер, вам нужно **только попросить у него тип**. Перечитайте мой комментарий выше, ведь на детском уровне объяснил максимально доходчиво. Если не понятно, то не `MemoryCacheBD.GetUserBD(Login);`, а `Services.GetService<IMemoryCacheBD>().GetUserDB(Login);`, где `Services` - это объект контейнера полученный каким либо образом (некоторые расширения имеют его, и там получается что-то типа `.Some((services, options) => { servicers.GetService.. } )`, но такое есть не у всех).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, вроде решил проблему